# How to make table view to display like flip animation in all devices in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3

In all devices the table view needs to be display only 70% of the screen irrespective of all devices and it should need to display only from bottom to top with animation and if I select anywhere on screen it should go to below and hide with animation I tried but unable to implement it can any one help me how to implement this ?

Here is my code

```
@IBAction func addtoCartButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: {
            self.addToCartTableView.isHidden = false
            self.addToCartTableView.delegate = self
            self.addToCartTableView.dataSource = self
            self.addToCartTableView.reloadData()
            self.addToCartTableView.frame.origin.y = 200
        }) { (Bool) in

        }

    }
 override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0.3, options: .autoreverse, animations: {

        }) { (Bool) in
            self.addToCartTableView.isHidden = true
        }
    }
    @IBAction func AddtoCartTableViewCloseButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
        self.addToCartTableView.isHidden = true
    }
```

[image: here is my image]

Comment: Tell me if this is what you want. Your tableView will appear from bottom to top with animation and if you tap anywhere else it will go down again with animation ? You can use transformation for this.

Comment: yes I need like as u told @sharadchauhan

Comment: So you are creating table using storyboard ?

Comment: yes I have layout in storyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you can use `CGAffineTransform`.

For example :

in `viewWillAppear()` do this :

```
addToCartTableView.alpha = 0.0
addToCartTableView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: addToCartTableView.bounds.origin.x, y: self.view.bounds.height)
```

And in you button action `addtoCartButtonAction` do this :

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: {
       self.addToCartTableView.delegate = self
       self.addToCartTableView.dataSource = self
       self.addToCartTableView.reloadData()
       self.addToCartTableView.transform = .identity
       self.addToCartTableView.alpha  = 1.0
}) { (Bool) in

}
```

And a tap gesture to your view and whenever you want to hide it again do this :

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: {
           self.addToCartTableView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: addToCartTableView.bounds.origin.x, y: self.view.bounds.height)
           self.addToCartTableView.alpha  = 0.0
    }) { (Bool) in

    }
```

Also you should not assign `self.addToCartTableView.delegate = self` `self.addToCartTableView.dataSource = self` in button action. Do that in `viewDidLoad()` or in `storyboard` only.

Comment: but tableview should display only 70% of screen height in all devices is it possible wth this ?

Comment: @User you have done that in storyboard right ? Just design you table like that in storyboard  that it will look like 70% of total height, for example the height constant will be 70% of you view.

Comment: but for different devices it is not maintaining height

Comment: if you can share your project share (on sharadchauhan0504@gmail.com ) so that I can look at your storyboard or else do proper auto-layout, it will work. And above answer is for animation only, it has nothing to with 70% height, that is maintained in storyboard only.

Comment: after clicking button it didn't display table view

Comment: check in button action if alpha is 1.0 not 0.0, I have updated my answer too.

Comment: it's 1.0 only but table view didn't display

Comment: make sure you are not hiding tableview anywhere. Just remove isHidden if its there in your code . Like this one self.addToCartTableView.isHidden